# Why isn't `white-space` consistent between IE and Firefox?

Tags: css, whitespace, word-wrap

I have `<span class="text">11-12.SL.1 Some long text</span>` where `text` has the following styles applied:

```
clear: left;
display: inline;
white-space: nowrap;
word-wrap: normal;
```

IE however, doesn't respect the `white-space` parameter.
[image: This is in IE]

vs Firefox, which respects it properly.
[image: This in FF]

How can I get IE to respect it?

Comment: What version of IE? You're on Windows XP, so it certainly can't be 9...

Comment: Can you post your code?  It is possible that your rule isn't specific enough for IE and that it is simply not being applied to the element.  What version of IE?

Comment: Could it be because of `word-wrap` which is a CSS3 property?

Comment: The `word-wrap` doesn't seem to be the issue. The `white-space` does. For reference, I'm using IE8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I needed to propagate the `white-space` up to the parents =)