# How can I force a `span` to not wrap at the end of a line?

Tags: css, word-wrap

If it's a really long line of text, I want it to extend without wrapping

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Try

```
span
{
  white-space: pre;
}
```

or [any other value that fits from the w3c spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#white-space-prop):

> **normal**
>   This value directs user agents to collapse sequences of white space, and break lines as necessary to fill line boxes.
>
> **pre**
>   This value prevents user agents from collapsing sequences of white space. Lines are only broken at preserved newline characters.
>
> **nowrap**
>   This value collapses white space as for 'normal', but suppresses line breaks within text.
>
> **pre-wrap**
>   This value prevents user agents from collapsing sequences of white space. Lines are broken at preserved newline characters, and as necessary to fill line boxes.
>
> **pre-line**
>   This value directs user agents to collapse sequences of white space. Lines are broken at preserved newline characters, and as necessary to fill line boxes.

[You should also be aware that there is limited IE support for some of the listed options](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/whitespace.html).

***WARNING, Cross-browser content messiness***: You could replace all spaces in the line with `&nbsp;`

Comment: None of them seem to work in IE, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014004/why-isnt-white-space-consistent-between-ie-and-firefox

Comment: @Shamoon I just tried it on IE9 and white-space:nowrap worked for me.

Answer (score 65):

CSS:

```
span
{
    white-space:nowrap
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're okay to make the spans an `inline-block`, you may want to try this:

```
display: inline-block;
width: max-content;
```